# couchbase: epmd: node name already occupied couchbase babysitter_of_ns_1

Tags: erlang, couchbase

```
Sep 15 12:45:36 build64 epmd: epmd: node name already occupied babysitter_of_ns_1
Sep 15 12:46:29 build64 epmd: epmd: Disallowed KILL_REQ, live nodes
Sep 15 12:50:58 build64 epmd: epmd: got KILL_REQ - terminates normal
Sep 15 13:03:29 build64 epmd: epmd: Disallowed KILL_REQ, live nodes
Sep 15 13:04:48 build64 epmd: epmd: got KILL_REQ - terminates normal
Sep 15 13:06:08 build64 epmd: epmd: Disallowed KILL_REQ, live nodes
```

But

```
$ sudo /opt/couchbase/bin/epmd -kill 
Killing not allowed - living nodes in database.

$ sudo /opt/couchbase/bin/epmd -names
epmd: up and running on port 4369 with data:
name babysitter_of_ns_1 at port 21100
```

after

```
# /etc/init.d/couchbase-server stop
Stopping couchbase-serverps
# ps auxwww|egrep "epm|couch"
#
```

How to find out why it does not start? Other nodes now in "pending" status.

PS Maybe "node name already occupied couchbase babysitter_of_ns_1" is the second attempt to start, and main error is "Disallowed KILL_REQ, live nodes"

PPS In general, the node on the other nodes in the cluster is shown as down, other nodes in "pend" state, and the port 8091 on broken node does not respond, although after the start of something started.

Comment: So what is your question? Are asking if this is indeed correct behavior? Or why are you getting the messages? Or why isn't it working?

Comment: why is't working and how to diag why.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you have a partial Couchbase instance still running. I would suggest terminating all processes owned by Couchbase and then try restarting. As root:

```
killall -u couchbase
ps -u couchbase
<verify no processes remain>
/etc/init.d/couchbase-server start
```

Comment: $ sudo ps -u couchbase  
  PID TTY          TIME CMD  
$  
  
Nothing, as in question.

Comment: This might also help: `ps -A | grep couch` and `kill` any it finds.